# Turn number representing total minutes into a datetime object in python

Tags: python, datetime

If I have a number representing a period I am interested in, for example the number 360 representing 360 minutes or 6 hours, how do I turn this into a datetime object such that I can perform the standard datetime object functions on it?

Similarly, if I have a datetime object in the format 00:30:00, representing 30 minutes, how do I turn that into a normal integer variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import datetime

t = datetime.timedelta(minutes=360)
```

This will create an object, `t`, that you can use with other datetime objects.

To answer the 2nd question you just edited in, you can use `t.total_seconds()` to return whatever your timedelta holds back into an integer in seconds. You'll have to do the conversion to minutes or hours manually though.

Comment: And to get from a timedelta to a datetime object, you need to specify a datetime endpoint that the timedelta was measured from, e.g. `datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 15, 14, 34)`. Then you can calculate `s+t`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at time deltas:

```
delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=360)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your time data is in '00:30:00' format then you should use `strptime`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time = '00:30:00'
>>> datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S).time()
datetime.time(0, 30)
```

If your data is in 30 (integer) format

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from time import strftime, gmtime
>>> minutes = timedelta(minutes=360)
>>> time = strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(minutes.total_seconds()))
>>> datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S').time()
datetime.time(6, 0)
```